# Android Options Menu is not visible/not called

Tags: java, android

I am using Google My Tracks code from [here](https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/) in my app.

Although in the app itselfthe menu bar is visible. when I integrate it in my app I cannot see the menu bar.

The code is exactly the same.

In the following code I cannot see the system.out.println message.

```
@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    System.out.println("Menu created");  
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.track_list, menu);

    menu.findItem(R.id.track_list_feedback)
        .setVisible(ApiAdapterFactory.getApiAdapter().isGoogleFeedbackAvailable());

    searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.track_list_search);
    ApiAdapterFactory.getApiAdapter().configureSearchWidget(this, searchMenuItem, trackController);

    startGpsMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.track_list_start_gps);
    refreshMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.track_list_refresh);
    exportAllMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.track_list_export_all);
    importAllMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.track_list_import_all);
    deleteAllMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.track_list_delete_all);
    return true;
  }
```

If it makes any difference, in all my other activities except the ones imported from this project, I do not use the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

If this code resides inside a Fragment, make sure you call [`setHasOptionsMenu(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu%28boolean%29) in `onCreate()` method of this Fragment.

Comment: It is a FragmentActivity and it says that setHasOptionsMenu is undefined for that type

Comment: The function must be there in Fragment. There is a link to javadoc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)